# Can I define parameters in an HTML / Ionic element?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need to define a value in an input field, not as an `element.value` but as a `data`, but I don't know how to do it in practice ... could someone give me a light in this darkness

**When I refer to the data, I mean information of type String or int value**

My Html element idea or something i want

```
 <ion-input #alpha type="text" data-datavalue="some Value" (ionChange)="functioEvent(data)"></ion-input>
```

My Script

```
fuctionEvent(data){

    console.log(this.data.datavalue);


}
```

Comment: I didnt get your question. Do you want to populate input field with your date string?

Comment: I want to pass a value from any string, like `John Doe` or a numeric value `44`  just like you do in javascript.

Comment: You are mixing `data` with `date`. Am I right?

Comment: I think I write it wrong, my failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make these changes. If you want to get data attribute from your angular template. First change `data` to `$event` Like this.

```
<ion-input #alpha type="text" data-datavalue="some Value" (ionChange)="functioEvent($event)"></ion-input>
```

and then in your .ts file.

```
fuctionEvent(event){
    console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-datavalue'));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can not handle data as a text input in Ionic, at least not out of the box. Besides I don't recommend you to do some weird handle of text as date and vice-versa.

Instead use `ion-datetime`, that is suitable widget for date input.

[Ionic Docs - Datetime](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime)

Comment: Okay, I realized the mistake I made in the question, when I refer to date, it is not time, but information of type Int or String